# How to copy text styling in LibreOffic Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm using LibreOffice to edit a spreadsheet originally created using Excel.  The text in some of the cells is styled, and I'd like to copy the formatting -- but not the contents -- from one cell to another.  How can I do that?

(This isn't any sort of conditional formatting, just ordinary color/background/bold/italic styling.)